# I Cant Launch Wine

Tags: wine

I installed Wine but when i want to launch it nothing happens. Even when I search for it in Search applications I cant find it. But in store it show that I have it installed. I also tried to reinstall the app and restart computer. Thank u for any advise

Comment: Wine is not a graphical application that you can "launch". There should be "Wine Setup". Run `wine` in a terminal.

Answer (score 10):

Try running `winecfg` in a terminal.  You should see a screen similar to this:

[image]

Normally you will use wine by entering commands like `wine [windowsprogram.exe]`